# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: spring, glassfish, jndi, ejb-3.1

I m creating a project that uses spring  + ejb3.1 + glassfish

Here the file configuration:

beans.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/dbaas" />

  <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="dbaasPU"/>

  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.manwin.dbaas.repository" />

  <tx:jta-transaction-manager />

  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
           <bean id="someId" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/> 



  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="dbaasPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/dbaas</jta-data-source>
  </persistence-unit>
```

A class

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class JobServiceImpl implements JobService{

    @Inject
    JobDaoJpa jobDaoJpa;
```

I got the follwoing error:

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'cloud-dbaas-PU' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a resource named `cloud-dbaas-PU`. Show us your resources.

Comment: No sorry the real error is: Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'dbaasPU' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,

Comment: I set up the configuration for the datasource in Glassfish, when i ping it, it works fine.

Comment: See how it says `Lookup failed for 'dbaasPU'`. That can only happen if you don't have such a resource. Show us the configuration.

Comment: The configuration of glassfish?

Comment: Yes, where is that JNDI resource defined?